# Is it safe to replace less-specific variable types with a new class that just inherits from the previously defined type?

Tags: c#, refactoring

For example, if I have a class such as this:

```
public class TestClass {
    public IDictionary<string, IList<IList<object>>> Variable {get; set;}
}
```

and I decided I need to use this type elsewhere, but don't want to keep using `IDictionary<string, IList<IList<object>>>` everywhere as it seems a bit smelly.. how "safe" is it for me to refactor the code by adding 2 more classes that look like this:

```
public class SubClass1 : Dictionary<string, SubClass2> {
}

public class SubClass2 : List<IList<object>>{
}
```

and changing my original class to look like this:

```
public class TestClass {
    public SubClass1 Variable {get; set;}
}
```

when there are potentially bits of code outside of my control (this DLL is referenced by other projects) that may be trying to use the original types? My assumption is that it will just be able to cast it naturally since its basically just the same code written in a slightly different way.. but are there any caveats to doing this I should be aware of, or is my assumption that this is safe just plain wrong?

Comment: What do you mean be safe? Whether libraries will be able to use your lib without recompilation?

Comment: Not necessarily without re-complication, but without having to change their code to match my new types, i.e it should be able to implicitly cast, right? That's my assumption here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not safe by any means, because, after your change:

```
// does not compile
IDictionary<string, IList<IList<object>>> x = new TestClass().Variable;
```

So any current code that did this will fail both at runtime (without recompilation) and in compile time. There are probably other ways it can fail, but one way is enough to show it's not safe.

Note that class from your question does not inherit old one (old one is interface), nor it implements old interface. If it did - it should have been more or less safe.

Comment: In response to your edit adding the note, that's one of the major reason's i'm asking here, since it's gone from being interfaces to classes. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @JamesTrotter yes but as you see - your new class does not even implement old interface, so it cannot be safe to make such replacement.

Answer (score 0):

It may be opinion-based but...

Lets describe some statements:

1. More strict contract can be simplified in the future
2. Class should be open for extension
3. Child class must not change bihavior of parent's one

Let's look at first case:

```
public class TestClass {
    public IDictionary<string, IList<IList<object>>> Variable {get; set;}
}
```

I have questions:

You expose `IDictionary` interface with all related methods (Add, Remove and so on), the same with `IList`. If one day you deside to forbid to modify it, you will have problems.

This:

```
public class SubClass1 : Dictionary<string, SubClass2> {
}
```

Will have the same problem because of inheritance, you see.

Maybe it's better to use composition with predefined methods:

```
public class SubClass1 {
    private IDictionary<string, IList<IList<object>>> _variable;

    public IList<IList<object>> GetData(string key) {
        return _variable[key];
    }
}
```

In the future, you can change `GetData` internals as you want, replace IDictionary to something else.

Also, I recommend to use `IReadOnlyList` interface to prevent corrupting data.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have the freedom to do that at this stage, though I do appreciate the merits to doing it this way.